# Can't install php7.4-bcmath on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, php-7.4, bcmath

There is a server on Ubuntu 18. Worth nginx and php 7.4
I need to install php7.4-bcmath

Command: "sudo apt-get install php7.4-bcmath" keeps giving error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-bcmath'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-bcmath'

Before doing the following commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

Does not help. If you try the command: sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
Version 7.2 will be installed. We don't need this.